# scala implement multiple generics types

Tags: scala

Please view this classes :

```
class MainClass(firstName:String) extends GenericClass[(Int,String,Long)](firstName,"David")
class GenericClass[T](str1: String, str2: String)
```

How scala can implement and map multiple type to single generic type ?
I mean GenericClass only have a Single type named `GenericClass[T]` but MainClass extends this and implement multiple type `GenericClass[(Int,String,Long)]`

I learn this code on slick orm :

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") { ... }
```

can do like this in java language ?

Comment: `(Int, String, Long)` is just tuple syntax. Java has not build-in special syntax for tuples, but you can use special classes, which serve a similar purpose to tuples, like `Pair<A,B>` from [javatuples](https://www.javatuples.org/index.html). Nothing then stops you from doing things like `GenericClass<Pair<String, String>>` in Java.

Comment: If you want something similar to Slick in Java, look at jOOQ. And yes, because Java does not have built-in tuple types, it uses things like `Record3<Integer, String, Long>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GenericClass[T]` has type parameter `T`. This parameter can be replaced by any type. In your case `GenericClass[T]` is parameterized by tuple `(Int,String,Long)` which is just a syntax sugar for `Tuple3[Int,String,Long]`, so you can replace one with another and nothing changes:

```
class MainClass(firstName:String) extends GenericClass[Tuple3[Int,String,Long]](firstName,"David")
```

Note: `Tuple3` is one type with three type parameters. Not multiple types.

As far as I know there is no equivalent of tuple class in java, but you can create it by your own or just use some librairies like [javatuples](https://www.javatuples.org/)